# Is it reasonable to leave a PhD if your supervisor leaves the university?

Tags: phd, advisor

I am a first year PhD student in Physics in a very important university in Germany. I started five months ago and unfortunately my first advisor is moving to a company. The university is important, but I actually chose to be there mainly to be supervised by her. She is well known in this field.

The topic is not my favourite one, but it is interesting and I've been working hard since the first day that I started.

However, I don't know why, the second supervisor is not considering me as a PhD student. In fact, we haven't had any meeting yet. On the other hand, I have a good working relationship with the third one.

At this point I don't know what I can do. I'm frustrated and sad since now I would like to make a different choice. Since it's my first year, I'm considering to move to another university even if less prestigious of this one. I'm here alone and I would have the possibility to be with my boyfriend.

By living this situation, maybe, I don't have the possibility to have a clear reasoning, so I need your help and advice in order to make the best choice possible. I'm considering to:

- Complete this year and move to another university next year in order to: (1) work on a more interesting topic, and (2) have the possibility to stay with my boyfriend.
- Remain here with few moral and supervised by professors that I didn't choose.

EDIT. I'm following the precious advice below to make a more general question. I remain of the idea that I'll consider only the two options above. Anyway, for me, and other PhD students in this situation, it'll be very useful to know other similar stories. With regard to this, **I'd like to understand if it's reasonable to leave a PhD when your supervisor leaves the university**. In particular, when you decided to apply for a particular university only to have the possibility to be supervised by a great professor, well known in his/her field. Unfortunately, differently from other stories where a supervisor moves to another university, in this case she leaves the university to move to a company. From other threads I understand that it's fundamental to maintain a good relationship with your ex-supervisor, since when you're already a PhD student and you decide to move, a reference letter from your ex-supervisor is critical since a transfer has to be highly justified.
Finally, I love this field and for me a PhD is the right pathway to follow, but at the same time **I'm scared because I don't know if a PhD transfer is easy to achieve**.

2nd EDIT. Maybe the bold sentences are too personal and a good answer cannot be given. So, I'd like to update the question in: **Is it reasonable to leave a PhD and apply for another university if your supervisor leaves?** In particular I'm trying to understand if the fact that you leave the PhD in a university can badly influence the application in the new university.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Unfortunately your question is not one that we (or anybody who doesn’t know you very well) can answer – see [this FAQ](//meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734).

Comment: The way you have phrased the two alternatives sounds like you know the answer already.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. @lighthousekeeper, yes, you're right. I was trying to understand if someone had my same situation. In particular, if my choice (suppose the first one) could be justified with the dereliction of my main supervisor.

Comment: @Christie Ah, I understand. This particular question sounds indeed important to me (and general enough that some Academia.SE users should be able to answer it, too). To make things clearer, you can edit your question to highlight this aspect. It might also be helpful if you can say whether your goal is a career in academia or industry (or you're undecided).

Comment: I agree, with some editing to focus on the question of handling the departure of your advisor, you can make this a more general question appropriate for Academia.SE.  Make sure you look through other similar questions though, to see if it's been answered.

Comment: Have you talked to your first advisor about the issue? A decent advisor doesn't leave her PhD students standing in the rain. Maybe she can help finding a better solution?

Comment: Take the first option and go for an interesting topic. Doing a PhD can be a rather frustrating thing. As a compensation, you should *love* your topic. Otherwise, you risk a high probability of failing.

Comment: Despite the special situation and the personal detail, I do not think that this question is off topic - it could need an edit to focus on the general question, though.

Comment: 5 months into a PhD is a good time to switch. It's a small fraction of a PhD and you still have many options. If the uni pays you, the options are more limited, but if it doesn't, then go on the offensive in finding other positions that will satisfy either your professional or your private requirements or both - it will pay off more than letting yourself fall into whatever wave rolls above you.

Answer (score 10):

First thing: **There is no such thing as "PhD transfer".** (At least in Germany.)

I don't know your university, but is the cases I know, you do not start any official PhD in the first year, but only later. Usually, you make an agreements with some advisor about the PhD thesis, working contracts and so on, and sometimes you enroll as a PhD student, but in most cases there is no official file at the university (but this may change in the near future…). At some point (where I am, usually in the last year) you fill in some form with which you start the official process of graduating (Eröffnung des Promotionsverfahrens or something similar).

So, if you haven't started the "Promotionsvorhaben" formally, you can quit and start new at any point.

More practically: **You should discuss your options with your advisor.** She is the right person for this. She may have suggestions how to proceed, e.g. she knows people who would like to take you as a student, she has a direct line to these people and will get a response quickly. She may help you to judge the possibilities that you have at the university where you are and she may also know you, your strength, and your preferences already.

Finally, I find the notion of "important university" a bit odd. There are some universities in Germany with a bit more overall prestige but there also also many not-so-well-known universities which are top at specific fields. So, the university name does not mean too much.

Answer (score 3):

In Germany the main question is: 
Is the new supervisor interested in the topic?

- has he other things planned?
- is the topic a long-thing with late payout?

Is he interested in you as a PHD student? If not, why not?

- is his standard higher?
- does he already have his people/students around him, who need funding?

To consider the impact of the result on your thesis, a lot depends on the specifics:

- is your PhD experimental -> having no support is a big problem, easily worth a lost year
- is your PhD experimental, but the direction of work (e.g. shared lab equipment, methods) are similar/identical -> you can try to cut a deal with the involved people
- is your PhD theoretical -> Do you feel that you have enough scientific interaction?
- how is the new working group? Well structured?
- do your skills make sense under the new supervisor (or did he/she bring in buddies which whom you would compete)?
- can you contribute to other peoples publications in the new group?
- How keen on publications is the new supervisor? (If he is very keen, then he does not give a shit what you do, as long as you deliver)

Is there a chair or a faculty ombudsman at the university which you could discuss this topic?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I haven't a new advisor yet, but I imagine that a new one will be assigned ASAP. Anyway, in the group there are other professors who study the same topic, but I can imagine that they have already their students. In any case, (1) he/she will be a new advisor who I didn't choose, (2) I will be a new PhD student that the professor didn't choose. I think that it's not very the best pre-condition to start. My PhD is experimental, in fact, I'm finding several efforts to handle this project without any guidance in the last period.

Comment: Let's say: i have seen people leaving PhDs under similiar circumstances. OTOH: If you get along with the new supervisor/the rest of the faculty and can cut a deal that you help ramp up the lab fast for being on many papers (so to say: the group member who was there before the group was there), it could be worth a shot. Are you already funded (DFG etc)? If yes, the other professors may be happy to take you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are unnecessarily complicating your decision:

1) Basing your decision in any substantial way on the location of your boyfriend is very unwise. He has not committed to you in any way, otherwise you'd at least be engaged to him. Even then, I think it would be unwise. At this point, you really have no certainty of a happy future with your boyfriend.

2) You're too "hung up" on the reputation of one individual. I'm certain there are plenty of other professors at your university who have solid reputations. You can't ride on the coat-tails of somebody else's reputation for the rest of your life. You have to establish your own reputation, and that doesn't depend upon being taught by a physics superstar. Other professors and students at the university might start to consider you to be a "whiner" if you are boo-hooing too much about the loss of your desired advisor. You may also look foolish if you move to another university because of this.

3) Your thinking about this issue doesn't seem to be very mature. "...I'm alone..." "...I'm sad..." "...My boyfriend..." "...not my favorite topic..." "...a more interesting topic..." All of these comments betray a certain immaturity on your part. It almost sounds like you've never had any real responsibility and you were spoiled by your parents.

This is my recommendation. You can take it or leave it:

Stay at your current, great university. Find a topic and advisor you can be happy with. Finish your degree and establish your reputation by working VERY hard. Meet up with your boyfriend for occasional fun weekends.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51911/discussion-on-answer-by-inquisitive-is-it-reasonable-to-leave-a-phd-if-your-supe).